# Ubuntu wine drop-down menus issue

Tags: package-management, wine, 18.04, window-manager, libraries

Environment:

Ubuntu 18.04

kernel 4.15

Crossover 17.5.0-1

Wine 2.8

There is an issue when selecting any drop-down menu in wine applications. Drop-down menus doesn't to be appear. The issue reproduces in clear wine, playonlinux, crossover.

For instance any of menus below doesn't open:

[image]

***Sometimes, for about 1/100 clicks it is appears on half a second.***

I'm more than sure that this is a problem in some kind of package/library,
coz i didn't face it several days ago.

I think this issue doesn't related to some `missing library`.

I tried to solve it using `opt/cxoffice/bin/cxfix --all` and `opt/cxoffice/bin/cxdiag` is fully satisfied.

Also i tried to disable all gnome extensions. And the issue doesn't correlate with that, because i didn't do any manipulations with extensions before normal work of drop-down menus and the appearance of this problem.

Tried to successfully remove/clear any package related to wine and cxoffice / playonlinux etc. Reinstalled crossover - and nothing happens.

**P.s.** while clicking the window is blinking and it seems that someone (maybe Gnome window manager) intercepts window management.

**UPDATE**

i posted an issue with some debug details for winehq community
https://forum.winehq.org/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=30642

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was related to Gnome settings.

Erasing all settings helped:

```
sudo rm -rf .gnome .gnome2 .gconf .gconfd .metacity .cache .dbus .dmrc .mission-control .thumbnails ~/.config/dconf/user ~.compiz*
```

I'l explore what setting exactly caused the issue.

**UPDATE**

I couldn't imagine that this sh*t setting could affect window management or something related !

[image]

`Allow different sources for each window` causes such weird wine windows behavior !

**P.s.** i can somehow understand such unacceptable errors as segfaults in gnome-software-center, BUT INPUT SOURCE, shame on you Gnome developers!